# Label is not being shown if I set the max y value to 100% and I have values higher than that

Tags: highcharts

I was taking a look at Highcharts documentation and I can't find a way to avoid the bar going higher than the max value defined for the y axis. The max needs to be 100% and any value above needs to get stick to the max, but displaying the correct value in the label (like 160%).

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
            type: 'column',
            spacingTop: 50,
            height: 500,
},
xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar']
},

yAxis: {
    max: 100,
    labels: {
                    useHTML: true,
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.value;
                    }
                }
},

series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4],
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      color: '#555',
      formatter: function() {
        return this.point.y + '%';
      }
    }
}]
```

});

[image: Percentage is not shown for columns with value over max]

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest the two solutions for your case.

1. Set the `dataLabels.inside` to true, which position labels in the column center.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Ld5kegah/

```
dataLabels: {
  enabled: true,
        inside: true,
        color: '#555',
  formatter: function() {
    return this.point.y + '%';
  }
}
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.dataLabels.inside

2. You can manually set wanted position of the dataLabel by using the load callback and the translate property.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/a593qxj4/

```
events: {
    render() {
        let chart =this,
                point = chart.series[0].points[2];
        
        point.dataLabel.translate(point.clientX - point.dataLabel.width / 2, 0)
    }
}
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#translate

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, but I need to display the number above the bar, not inside.

Comment: @ChrisLopo, so change the `y` value in the translate function - https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qwu5s7yc/

Comment: Almost perfect! I just need to apply this formatting for any value above 100.

Comment: Something like this should do a job: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vbL5m0ya/

Comment: Could you accept the answer then? Could be useful for future users which will struggle with the same answer.